C programming tic tac toe error "more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat-insufficient-args]"
I'm new to C programming, this is my f (tic tac toe) ist C program [ please do not eat me alive , i've searched and scrolled but cant find seem ti find a way to fix this] I've followed a C programming Tutorial and I am not sure where Im going wrong.
Sometimes winner is declared and sometimes winner is not declared. Also sometimes values from 4-6 are accepted in column and sometimes not ( numbers to chose from set to 3).
If anyone could point out where I went wrong, i would be more than grateful.
ALSO :

Im getting the following warning :
 [{
    "resource": "/Users/programming/projects/cprogrammingprojects/tic-tac-toe/tictactoe.c",
    "owner": "cpptools",
    "severity": 4,
    **"message": "more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat-insufficient-args]**",
    "source": "gcc",
    "startLineNumber": 73,
    "startColumn": 13,
    "endLineNumber": 73,
    "endColumn": 13
}]

**Below is my code **


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>



char board [3][3];
const char PLAYER = 'X';
const char COMPUTER = 'O';


void resetBoard();
void printBoard();
int checkFreeSpaces();
void playerMove();
void computerMove();
char checkWinner();
void printWinner(char);


int main()
{

  char winner = ' ';
  char response;

  do
  {
    winner = ' ';
    response = ' ';

    resetBoard();

    while (winner == ' ' && checkFreeSpaces() != 0)
    {
      printBoard();
    
    
      playerMove();             
      winner = checkWinner(); 
      if (winner != ' ' || checkFreeSpaces() == 0) 
      {
        break;                     
      }                   
         
    
      computerMove();           
      winner = checkWinner(); 
      if (winner != ' ' || checkFreeSpaces() == 0)  
      {
        break;                     
      }                            
    
    }
  
    printBoard();
    printWinner(winner);

    printf("\nWould you like to play again? (Y/N): ");
    scanf("%c"); 
    scanf("%c", &response);
    response = toupper(response);

  } while (response == 'Y');

  printf("THANKS FOR PLAYING!\n");


  return 0;
}



void resetBoard()
{
  for(int i=0; i< 3; i++)
  {
      for(int j=0; j< 3; j++)
    {
        board[i][j] = ' ';

    }
  }
}

void printBoard()
{

  printf(" %c | %c | %c ", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2]);
  printf("\n---|---|---\n");
  printf(" %c | %c | %c ", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2]);
  printf("\n---|---|---\n");
  printf(" %c | %c | %c ", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2]);
  printf("\n");

}

int checkFreeSpaces()

{
  int freeSpaces = 9;
  
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
      if (board[i][j] != ' ')
      {
        freeSpaces--;
      }    
    }
  }
  
  return freeSpaces;
}


void playerMove()
{
  
  int x;
  int y;

  do
  
  {
    printf("Enter Row # (1-3): ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    x--;

    printf("Enter Column # (1-3): ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    y--;

    if(board [x][y] != ' ')
    {
      printf("Invalid move!\n");
    }
    else 
    {
      board[x][y] = PLAYER;
      break; 
    }

  } while (board[x][y] != ' ');
 
}

void computerMove()   
{                     
 
 srand(time(0));
 
  int x;
  int y;

  if (checkFreeSpaces() > 0)

  {

    do
    {
     x = rand() %3;
     y = rand() %3;
    } while (board[x][y] != ' ');

    board[x][y] = COMPUTER;
  }

  else
  {
    printWinner(' ');   
  }

}

char checkWinner()  
{   

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    if (board[i][0] == board[i][1] && board[i][0] == board[i][2])
    
    {
      return board[i][0];    
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    if (board[0][i] == board[1][i] && board[0][i] == board[2][i])
    
    {
      return board[0][i];    
    }
  }

  
    if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[2][2])
    
    {
      return board[0][0];    
    }
  
  {
    if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[0][2] == board[2][0])
    
    {
      return board[0][2];    
    }

    return ' ';
  } 

}


void printWinner(char winner)
{

  if(winner == PLAYER)
  {
    printf("YOU WIN !\n");
  }
  
  else if(winner == COMPUTER)

  {
    printf("YOU LOSE!\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("IT'S A TIE\n");
  }
 
}

This is my terminal output, when i play around with the program. As you can see, numbers above 3 are accepted sometimes ,and sometimes not. And also a winner not being declared at times. if anyone can help me out there, i will greatly benefit from your response. Tank you

   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 6
Enter Column # (1-3): 6
Invalid move!
Enter Row # (1-3): 3
Enter Column # (1-3): 6
Invalid move!
Enter Row # (1-3): 5
Enter Column # (1-3): 2
Invalid move!
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 7
Invalid move!
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 2
 O |   |   
---|---|---
   | X |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 3
Enter Column # (1-3): 1
 O |   |   
---|---|---
 O | X |   
---|---|---
 X |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 1
Enter Column # (1-3): 3
 O |   | X 
---|---|---
 O | X |   
---|---|---
 X |   |   
YOU WIN !

Would you like to play again? (Y/N): y
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 4
   |   |   
---|---|---
   | O |   
---|---|---
 X |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 6
Enter Column # (1-3): 6
Invalid move!
Enter Row # (1-3): 3
Enter Column # (1-3): 6
Invalid move!
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 7
Invalid move!
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 5
   |   |   
---|---|---
   | O |   
---|---|---
 X | X | O 
Enter Row # (1-3): 1
Enter Column # (1-3): 1
 X | O |   
---|---|---
   | O |   
---|---|---
 X | X | O 
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 3
 X | O |   
---|---|---
 O | O | X 
---|---|---
 X | X | O 
Enter Row # (1-3): 1
Enter Column # (1-3): 3
 X | O | X 
---|---|---
 O | O | X 
---|---|---
 X | X | O 
IT'S A TIE/

Would you like to play again? (Y/N): y
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 4
   |   |   
---|---|---
   | O |   
---|---|---
 X |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 6
   |   |   
---|---|---
 O | O |   
---|---|---
 X |   | X 
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 5
   |   |   
---|---|---
 O | O | O 
---|---|---
 X | X | X 
Enter Row # (1-3): 1
Enter Column # (1-3): 1
 X |   |   
---|---|---
 O | O | O 
---|---|---
 X | X | X 
YOU LOSE!

Would you like to play again? (Y/N): y
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 1
Enter Column # (1-3): 1
 X |   |   
---|---|---
   | O |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 1
Enter Column # (1-3): 2
 X | X |   
---|---|---
   | O |   
---|---|---
   |   | O 
Enter Row # (1-3): 3
Enter Column # (1-3): 3
Invalid move!
Enter Row # (1-3): 1
Enter Column # (1-3): 3
 X | X | X 
---|---|---
   | O |   
---|---|---
   |   | O 
YOU WIN !

Would you like to play again? (Y/N): y
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 1
   | O |   
---|---|---
 X |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 2
   | O |   
---|---|---
 X | X |   
---|---|---
   |   | O 
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 3
   | O |   
---|---|---
 X | X | X 
---|---|---
   |   | O 
YOU WIN !

Would you like to play again? (Y/N): y
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 3
Enter Column # (1-3): 1
   | O |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
 X |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 3
Enter Column # (1-3): 2
   | O |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
 X | X | O 
Enter Row # (1-3): 3
Enter Column # (1-3): 3
Invalid move!
Enter Row # (1-3): 1
Enter Column # (1-3): 1
 X | O |   
---|---|---
   |   | O 
---|---|---
 X | X | O 
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 1
 X | O |   
---|---|---
 X |   | O 
---|---|---
 X | X | O 
YOU WIN !

Would you like to play again? (Y/N): y
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 3
Enter Column # (1-3): 3
   |   | O 
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   | X 
Enter Row # (1-3): 3
Enter Column # (1-3): 2
   |   | O 
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
 O | X | X 
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 2
   |   | O 
---|---|---
 O | X |   
---|---|---
 O | X | X 
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 3
 O |   | O 
---|---|---
 O | X | X 
---|---|---
 O | X | X 
YOU LOSE!

Would you like to play again? (Y/N): y
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 4
Enter Column # (1-3): 1
Invalid move!
Enter Row # (1-3): 2
Enter Column # (1-3): 4
   |   |   
---|---|---
   |   | O 
---|---|---
 X |   |   
Enter Row # (1-3): 


When you have scanf (or printf) with a format specifier, the you must pass a suitable argument. Unless you use a format that is explicitly documented as not needing an argument. So please take some time to think about scanf("%c").

Also, if your goal is to skip leading whitespace, then simply add a single space in your format string, like scanf(" %c", &response) (note the space before the %)

And for future questions that is about compiler warnings or errors, first of all try to create a [mre] to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part. Then copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build-log into the question. Oh and add comments on the lines in the code that the errors or warnings are about.

If you are new to C, perhaps you have not yet heard the oft repeated advice: do not use scanf.  Ever.  Just don't use it.  It's only purpose is as an educational toy, and it fails spectacularly at that.  You will spend many hours debugging stupid scanf issues which teach you (almost) nothing about the language.  At least read: https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Welcome to SO. A few remarks regarding compiler errors or warnings: 1) If you ask about compiler warnings, there is no point in running your program and showing the output. The warning happens before you run the program. It only depends on the code, not on any input. 2) If you get a compiler warning or error, the warning extremely rarely depends on anything that comes later in your code. That means, except for those cases (like "#if without matching #endif" or similar) it doesn't make much sense to include any code after the function where you got the message. That is just waste of time.


Your compiler does not care about the purpose of your program. Nor does the error message depend on it. Therefore your title should not mention tic tac toe, but only something related to the error or warning.


The compiler is telling you that scanf("%c") is a terrible thing to write.  I suspect you are trying to consume some whitespace (a newline) with that line of code, but that is the wrong way to do it.   Consider what that line of code will do.  scanf is going to (try to) read a byte of data from the input stream, and it will write that byte somewhere.  Since you have not provided the address of a location to write the data, the compiler will generate code that ... does something.  ( Exactly what it will do is "undefined".  In practice, it will probably generate code that will write a byte of data to some arbitrary location in memory which may have no impact at all, or it may have catastrophic consequences and crash your program.  The behavior is undefined. )
The compiler is giving you that warning to tell you that the code you have written is probably not doing what you desire, and you should change it.  In particular, if you are going to use a "%c" format string with scanf, you must pass a corresponding argument which is the address of a memory location to which scanf should write the byte that it reads.
But if you are trying to consume whitespace, just use a space in the next scanf call (" %c").
